# Задать значения ячейки для новой колонки DataFrame согласно условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть словарь вида:

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

и есть датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 'a', 'b']})
```

Как сделать новую колонку и в нее передать значения из словаря. То есть, если в первой колонке `a`, то в новой колонке должно быть число `1`. DataFrame должен получиться таким:

```
col | new_col
-------------
a   |  1
a   |  1
b   |  2
```

Есть идея бегать через метод `iterrow` и проверять в условии значение колонки.

Eсть ли способ эффективнее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].map(a)
```

---

результат:

```
In [59]: df
Out[59]:
  col  new
0   a    1
1   a    1
2   b    2
```